# How to configure filebeat to handle log rotation?

Tags: logging, supervisord, filebeat, log-rotation

## My settings

I have a docker cluster in which `supervisord` is writing logs to `output.log` on a shared volume, from which `Filebeat` is reading and shipping logs to ES. In order to prevent disk-full problems, I have configured `supervisord` to rotate the logs, and I'm worried that Filebeat might miss out logs or send logs twice.

## My problem

I would like Filebeat to consume the logs written to `output.log`, without duplication or missing out log lines.

## My question

How do I configure Filebeat to handle `supervisord` log rotation?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like [`supervisord` rotation](http://supervisord.org/logging.html) works with filebeat out of the box.

For example, in the `program` section of `supervisord.conf`, the following configuration rotated the logs, and filebeat did not miss a single line.

```
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1024
stdout_logfile_backups=5
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1024
stderr_logfile_backups=5
```

It is worth to mention that in real production system I would use larger values (in the dozens or hundreds of MBs), so that Filebeat will not miss the files when *all* the files are rotated during its sleep interval.

Comment: Can you provide an example of filebeat configuration?